# How to deduct total amount when deleted on the datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I have a school program which is the ordering system. 
I have 3 buttons namely add order, delete order, update order.

I need some help on the subtraction part
in which the selected rows and the cell where column name **Amount** belong will be deducted from the `txtTotalAmount`

[image: Here's the picture for reference if not understood]

I already did the addition part like when add order button clicked total Amount textbox sum it 
Here's the code:

```
int totalx = 0;  
int Totalxr = int.Parse(txtTotal.Text);
totalx += Totalxr;
txtTotalAmount.Text = totalx.ToString();
```

I tried the subtraction part but I failed to do it.
Here's my code

```
int Totalxr = int.Parse(txtTotal.Text);
int txrs = int.Parse(txtTotalAmount.Text);
int str = txrs - Totalxr;
txtTotalAmount.Text = str.ToString();
```

clarification of what I want to achieved.

Example the total would be 7300.

if selected row has an amount of 4300 which is shown in the image above  then totalamount textbox should update when it is deleted and making the total amount of 3000. then again if user again selects the row with 3000 under the column amount the totalamount will be updated from 3000 to 0 since the selected row amount has 3000 and the current total is 3000.

Hope I already clarify what I wanted to do.

Lastly Why I can't remove the `txtAmount.text`which I will be doing after add order is successful
like when I used `txtAmount.Clear();` the text is still there. while the other txts which I use the clear function works.

Comment: What error or exception are you getting here ?

Comment: What error you are getting? try to get Totalxr value from girdview's current row

Comment: Its not working
try to change to gridview's current row
after I click the delete order surely it delete but the value is mismatched
like on the current row has 4000 on it, the other row has 2000. When I delete the current row 4000 must be deducted from the total amount but it deduct the 2000

lastly It throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thank you for the help